# How do I keep the source view controller from disappearing after a push segue?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

First off, this is my view controller/segue setup:
[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder]

The three rightmost view controllers' background views are UIVisualEffectViews through which the source view controllers should be visible. They were added in the various `viewDidLoad()`s like this:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

self.tableView.backgroundView = blurEffectView
```

Now, the main view controller (the "Garbage Day" one) is visible through the settings view controller, but the settings VC disappears whenever one of the two rightmost VCs is fully on screen. Here's a screen recording:

[Screen recording of the source view controller dis- and reappearing](https://gfycat.com/JealousWillingCassowary)

(Please ignore the glitches, the app I used to upload this apparently corrupted the video)

I get that technically, the Show segue doesn't have the "Over Current Context" thingy and therefore, I shouldn't expect the source VC to not disappear, but there has to be a way to make this work without custom segues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a custom transition between view controllers.

I just wrote and tested this class:

```
class AnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
{
    var pushing = true

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.3
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

        let toVc = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)!
        let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!

        let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!

        let container = transitionContext.containerView

        if pushing {
            container.addSubview(fromView)
            container.addSubview(toView)
        }

        var finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVc)
        if pushing {
            finalFrame.origin.x = finalFrame.width
            toView.frame = finalFrame
            finalFrame.origin.x = 0
        } else {
            finalFrame.origin.x = finalFrame.width
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            if self.pushing {
                toView.frame = finalFrame
            } else {
                fromView.frame = finalFrame
            }
        }) { (_) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            if self.pushing {
                container.insertSubview(fromView, belowSubview: toView)
            } else {
                fromView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your `UINavigationController` class do the following:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    let animationController = AnimationController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self
    }
}
```

And this extension:

```
extension NavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        animationController.pushing = operation == .push

        return animationController
    }
}
```

However, this makes you lose the interactive dismiss gesture (Swiping from the left of the screen to dismiss) So you would need to fix that yourself.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks for the transition code, but I think I'll just drop the blurred background entirely.